# I can't edit files in AppCode 1.5

Tags: mobile, appcode

I have a source code of IPhone App and i am on windows,

I install OSX on VirsualBox, And also install AppCode, Then open the project and try to edit some files it's not allowed i mean when double clicking on files or  click Jump to source in context menu file not opened in the editor, i just want to change some configurations in file: "Configration.h"

I want to change this var:

> `#define AAID @"ca-app-pub-0000000/00000"`

If it can't be editable with appcode is there any way to compile without Xcode ?

Comment: I don't think you can compile without Xcode, since you're probably missing the developer tools (xcrun, xcodebuild, etc. )

Comment: You must have an installed Xcode alongside AppCode. Also, version 1.5 is an antique, and likely not to work at all with current Xcodes.

Answer (score 0):

To use AppCode you should install Xcode first, because AppCode uses xcodebuild for building and LLDB bundled in Xcode for debugging. As was mentioned in the comments above, AppCode 1.5 is too old and for now you should use AppCode 2016.1 that can be downloaded from the [product page](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/download/)